# SapUI5: List item with a toggle (hide/show) for another List Item

Tags: javascript, list, sapui5

Hey UI5 is a framework which has many possibilities but sometimes I crush with ideas (which would be probably easier in normal HTML) against the walls.
That's what I want: A List with ListItems displaying Cities for example Berlin, Los Angeles, Moskau etc. On this listen you then can click on an icon (preferred but can be a button too). If clicked Icon displays then another ListItem so it displays an address. If you then lick that ListItem you get a map -the map part is working and it would work with the list if it would have one StandardListItem. The problem? It's bad for displaying things like I want!

Example:

- Berlin -> click -> show -> 123456 Example Street
- Moskau
- Los Angeles

or:

- Berlin
- Moskau
- Los Angeles -> click -> show -> 654321 Example Adress

code I have :

NOTE: I deleted some of the code so you get only the necessary part of it

view:

```
    <List   id="campusList"
            items="{
                path: '/',
                sorter: {
                    path: 'city',
                    descending: false
                }
            }"
            mode="SingleSelectMaster"
            itemPress="handleListItemPress"
            growing="true">

        <InputListItem  label="{city}" >

            <core:Icon src="sap-icon://navigation-down-arrow" press="showDetails" />
            <StandardListItem type="Navigation" title="{buildingName}" description="{buildingDesc}" />

        </InputListItem>
    </List>
```

controller:

```
jQuery.sap.require("www.adress.com.GeneralHelper");

sap.ui.controller("www.adress.com.LocationList", {

    onInit: function() {

        var bus = sap.ui.getCore().getEventBus();
        bus.subscribe("content", "updateSuccess", this.updateSuccess, this);

        sap.ui.getCore().getEventBus().publish("content", "update", {
            id : "Location"
        });
    },

    updateSuccess: function (channelID , eventID, data) {

        if (data.id === "Location") {

            var oModel = sap.ui.getCore().getModel("LocationModel");
            oModel.setDefaultBindingMode(sap.ui.model.BindingMode.OneWay);
            this.getView().setModel(oModel);

            if (!jQuery.device.is.phone) {
                //preselect entry
                var self = this;
                var oList = this.byId("campusList");
                oList.attachUpdateFinished(function(evt) {
                    if (oList.getItems().length > 0) {
                        var oContext = new sap.ui.model.Context(self.getView().getModel(), "/0");
                        oList.setSelectedItem(oList.getItems()[0], true);
                        sap.ui.getCore().getEventBus().publish("nav", "to", {
                            id: "LocationDetail",
                            data : oContext
                        });
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    },

    handleListItemPress : function (evt) {
        sap.ui.getCore().getEventBus().publish("nav", "to", {
            id : "LocationDetail",
            data : evt.getParameters().listItem.getBindingContext()
        });
    }
});
```

and I also have a local-demo-data-json wich is loaded from a UpdateHelper.

PS:I would like to not use $().hide, $().show and other jquery things i would prefer UI5.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to show or hide a list item you can use

```
myListItem.setVisible(true) //or
myListItem.setVisible(false)
```

but what you can also do is use a custom list item, put all the extra information into a `new sap.m.Panel()`, and add that Panel into your custom list item on click (and destroy it/set it to invisible to hide the extra information).

Comment: the first thing is pretty obvius, i don't know  why I didn't come to this !

but the second one iis a bit hard for me to understand.
I rarely use "new sap.m.example" because i use xmlviews but maybe im just misunderstanding?
Please consider to give me a code example.

Comment: never mind the "new sap.m.example" then. Set a panel with the detailed information inside your list item to visible/invisible on click